# R - Filter List Using First Element of Each Item in the List

Tags: r, list, subset, purrr

I'm fairly new to R and I'm trying to parse data from a PDF into a data table. I've been able to parse the text into a list, but I'm having a hard time trying to filter data from the list.

As an example, consider the sample list below:

```
l_vectors <- list( c("K", "10", "20"),
                   c("1", "30", "40"),
                   c("a", "b", "c"),
                   c("x", "y", "z"))
```

Let's say I'd like to filter this list so it only includes the vectors starting with "K" or "1"

I can use map_lgl to find get a logical vector indicating which list items are a match

```
map_lgl(l_vectors, function(x) x[1] == "K" | x[1] == "1" )
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

From hear I'm not quite sure the best direction. I'm guessing that I'd want to use this logical vector in  combination with pluck, but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers,
Jonathon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `keep` to loop over the `list` of `vector`s and create a logical vector of length 1 with `str_detect` wrapped with `any`.  Here the pattern checked is the character "K" or (`|`) "1" from the start (`^`) of the string

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
keep(l_vectors, ~ any(str_detect(.x, "^(K|1)")))
#[[1]]
#[1] "K"  "10" "20"

#[[2]]
#[1] "1"  "30" "40"
```

If we check only the first element, no need for `any` to be wrapped

```
keep(l_vectors, ~ str_detect(.x[1], "^(K|1)"))
#[[1]]
#[1] "K"  "10" "20"

#[[2]]
#[1] "1"  "30" "40"
```

If it is a fixed match, then as in @markus post, can use `%in%`

```
keep(l_vectors,  ~ .x[1] %in% c("K", "1"))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use baseR you can write a helper function and then use `Filter`

```
f <- function(x) x[1] %in% c("K", "1")
Filter(f, l_vectors)
#[[1]]
#[1] "K"  "10" "20"

#[[2]]
#[1] "1"  "30" "40"
```

---

This could also be written as

```
Filter(function(x) x[1] %in% c("K", "1"), l_vectors)
```